# Optional JSX Props In a TSX/JSX Project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, react-tsx

I have a React project that I'm converting from JS to TS. An issue I'm running into is that TSX React is assuming that all properties defined in a functional component are required props.

```
// ComponentA.tsx
class ComponentA extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    /* Type '{ equalWidth: true; children: Element[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ children: any; className: any; equalWidth: any; }'.
     * Property 'className' is missing in type '{ equalWidth: true; children: Element[]; }'.' */
    return <ComponentB equalWidth />
  }
}
```

and

```
// ComponentB.js
const ComponentB = ({ children, className, equalWidth }) => {
  return (...)
}
```

is there a way to signal to TS that JSX component props are all optional?

Comment: Related - [Optional property on a component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65981948/104380)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One simplest option will be setting a default value for your optional props. As an example, if `className` is optional you can change your `ComponentB.js` to something like this.

```
const ComponentB = ({ children, className="", equalWidth }) => {
  return (...)
}
```

Also if you deconstruct your props in the function body instead of the signature TS will not complain about typings.

```
const ComponentB = (props) => {
  const { children, className, equalWidth } = props;
  return (...)
}
```

Comment: Good solution! The issue is that TS assumes that if you have `onClick = null`, `onClick`'s type is the literal `null` - instead of `null` as a default

Comment: I'm going to give the bounty to you. Although the solution isn't _exactly_ what I was looking for - there are some issues (as I've described in my comment above) - it's fairly easy and straight forward to work around. Thanks!

Comment: @TylerSebastian I'm glad if it helped you somehow

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that `ComponentB.js` is going to end up as a TypeScript component:

```
interface ComponentBProps {
    children?: ReactNode;
    className?: string;
    equalWidth?: boolean;
}

const ComponentB = ({ children, className, equalWidth }: ComponentBProps) => {
    // 
};
```

In the special case where all properties are optional, you could remove the `?` from each property on the interface and use `Partial<ComponentBProps>`, but I guess that at least something will end up being a required prop.

---

If you want to keep `ComponentB.js` as it is, then an alternative solution is to create a type definitions file:

```
import { ReactNode, StatelessComponent } from "react";

interface ComponentBProps {
    children?: ReactNode
    className?: string;
    equalWidth?: boolean;
}

export const ComponentB: StatelessComponent<ComponentBProps>;
```

If you put in this the same directory as the JavaScript file and name is `ComponentB.d.ts`, then you should be able to import `ComponentB` in your TypeScript file.

The way I have written the definition assumes that the component is a **named export**, not the default, i.e. it is exported like `export const ComponentB` in the `.js` file.

#### (probably) working example: https://github.com/fenech/tsx-jsx

Comment: Well, yes and no: yes, `ComponentB` is eventually going to be converted to TypeScript, but not at the moment. I can't annotate a `.js` file, so I can't add in TS types - and if that was a possibility, I would be able to just annotate it properly, then.

Comment: @Tyler I made a little example which uses a `.d.ts` file and added a link